# Constraints errors when call bar appears

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Morning

How to correct errors constraints when the call bar appears. I do not have this problem when it is hidden.

I have this error

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.

Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.

Try this:

    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;

    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.

(

    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc4ba591630 V:|-(20)-[UIInputSetContainerView:0x7fc4ba58f310]   (Names: '|':UITextEffectsWindow:0x7fc4bc17b950 )>",

    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc4bc157c10 'UIInputWindowController-top' V:|-(0)-[UIInputSetContainerView:0x7fc4ba58f310]   (Names: '|':UITextEffectsWindow:0x7fc4bc17b950 )>"

)


Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc4ba591630 V:|-(20)-[UIInputSetContainerView:0x7fc4ba58f310]   (Names: '|':UITextEffectsWindow:0x7fc4bc17b950 )>
```

Thanks